# Tracker.Current is not initialized for RSS page

Tags: xdb, rss, tracking

We're getting a ton of errors from an RSS page on one of the websites when bots hit it to get/parse RSS:

```
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Tracker.Current is not initialized
Source: Sitecore.Analytics
at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.StartAnalytics.StartTracking.Process(PipelineArgs args)
at (Object , Object[] )
at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.HttpRequest.StartAnalytics.Process(RenderLayoutArgs args)
```

There are thousands of errors in logs. The RSS page is fairly standard - using standard FeedDeliveryLayout.

```razor
<%@ Page Language="c#" EnableSessionState="false" EnableViewState="false" Inherits="Sitecore.Syndication.Web.FeedDeliveryLayout, Sitecore.Kernel" CodePage="65001" %>
```

I disabled analytics a few hours ago for this page by going to Appearance ->Tracking ->Attributes ->Settings ->Disable analytics. There are still errors in the log though.

Are there any other settings I need to change to disable analytics for this page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason the tracker is not initialized is because it can't work with session state disabled.

As I understand, you don't want this page to be tracked anyway. To ensure that xDB tracking is disabled, just add the following code into the page:

```cs
<script runat="server">

protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    Tracker.Enabled = false;
}

</script>
```

This way, the `startAnalytics` pipeline will be aborted way before the `StartTracking` processor, which is where your exceptions occur.

You may have to add the following lines at the top of the page:

```aspx
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Sitecore.Analytics" %>
```

Comment: Thanks! Could this just go directly into sitecore\shell\Applications\Feeds\Layouts\FeedDeliveryLayout.aspx ?

Comment: @alexp83 Yes, that's exactly where I meant it to go!

Comment: As a follow-up, what does 'Disable Analytics' option do when enabled from the 'Tracking' field in Sitecore? Seems like it should be disabling analytics and tracking altogether...

Comment: @alexp83 Yes, to my understanding, it's supposed to do that, but for some reason, that feature doesn't always work. I would advise to raise this with Sitecore Support.

Answer (score 3):

The `Disable Analytics` option on item is used during the Processing/Aggregation activities of Sitecore Analytics, specifically the **processItem** pipeline.

```xml
<processItem patch:source="Sitecore.Analytics.config">
  <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.ProcessItem.CollectParameters,Sitecore.Analytics"/>
  <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.ProcessItem.TriggerCampaigns,Sitecore.Analytics"/>
  <processor type="Sitecore.ExperienceExplorer.Business.Pipelines.ProcessItem.InteractionValuePipeline, Sitecore.ExperienceExplorer.Business" patch:source="Sitecore.ExperienceExplorer.config"/>
  <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.ProcessItem.RegisterPageEvents,Sitecore.Analytics"/>
  <processor type="Sitecore.ExperienceExplorer.Business.Pipelines.ProcessItem.SaveInitialProfilesPipeline, Sitecore.ExperienceExplorer.Business" patch:source="Sitecore.ExperienceExplorer.config"/>
  <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.ProcessItem.ProcessProfiles, Sitecore.Analytics"/>
  <processor type="Sitecore.ExperienceExplorer.Business.Pipelines.ProcessItem.ProfilesPipeline, Sitecore.ExperienceExplorer.Business" patch:source="Sitecore.ExperienceExplorer.config"/>
</processItem>
```

The reason you are seeing the error pop-up, even on the default FeedDeliveryLayout is because of the **startAnalytics** pipeline. As Dmytro points out, manually setting the `Tracker.Enable` to false on the layout is a way of telling Sitecore to ignore tracking for that request, which checked in the `CheckPreconditions` processor of the same pipeline.

Interesting to note, other reasons why this pipeline would not proceed:

- `Tracker.Enable` is `false`
- `SiteContext` is null
- `Context.Page` is null
- `site.Tracking().EnableTracking() is`false`

```xml
<startAnalytics patch:source="Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config">
  <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.StartAnalytics.CheckPreconditions, Sitecore.Analytics"/>
  <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.StartAnalytics.CreateTracker, Sitecore.Analytics"/>
  <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.StartAnalytics.StartTracking, Sitecore.Analytics"/>
</startAnalytics>
```

Specifically the `StartTracking` processor:

```cs
  public class StartTracking
  {
    public virtual void Process(PipelineArgs args)
    {
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) args, "args");
      Assert.IsNotNull((object) Tracker.Current, "Tracker.Current is not initialized");
      Tracker.Current.StartTracking();
      Log.Debug("[Analytics]: Start tracking: " + (object)         

      ... code snipped ...

    }
  }
```

The Assert is Not Null is throwing the error.  If you wanted to manually fix the way this reports, you could create a custom processor that goes before `StartAnalytics`, and instead of doing a `Assert.IsNotNull` at the begging, you could check for null, perform a `Log.Debug()` signifying that the Tracker is null here, and then gracefully abort out of the pipeline.

```cs
public class CheckNullTracker
{
    public virtual void Process(PipelineArgs args)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)args, "args");

        if (Tracker.Current == null)
        {
            Log.Debug("Tracker.Current is not initialized");
            Tracker.Enabled = false;
            args.AbortPipeline();
        }
    }
}
```

> The above custom processor is more of a fundamental example. Care
>   should be taken. The `Tracker.Current` use case is utilized in a whole
>   bunch of pipeline processors and other areas.  Appropriate uses of Tracker should always include a check to ensure `Tracker.Current` is ***not*** `null`.